# A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected. - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am pretty new to PowerBI, but hoping someone can help me out here.

I have two data sources, one called Workday and one called Phishing Results. The idea is to bring over the SVP, VP, Director, and Manager from Workday to Phishing Results similar to a VLOOKUP function in Excel. I am using LOOKUPVALUE, and it works for SVP, VP, and Manager. But when I use the exact same DAX query for Director, I get the following error:

"A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected."

[image: Workday Table]

VP Query that works

```
VP = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    'Workday Report'[VP], 
    'Workday Report'[Work Email Address], 'Phishing Results'[Email]
)
```

Manager Query that works

```
Manager = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    'Workday Report'[Manager], 
    'Workday Report'[Work Email Address], 'Phishing Results'[Email]
)
```

Director Query that doesn't work

```
Director = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    'Workday Report'[Director], 
    'Workday Report'[Work Email Address],'Phishing Results'[Email]
)
```

[image: Phishing Results Table]

[image: Table Relationships]

Comment: Can you please also provide some sample data from the other table?

Comment: @mkRabbani I added a screenshot of the phishing results table

Comment: Is there any relation between those 2 tables? If yes, say details of that relation. Is email between both table contain one to one data?

Comment: @mkRabbani yes, the email address field is my key and I have a relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Does `Workday Report` table always contain only one row for any given `Work Email Address`? `LOOKUPVALUE` expects exactly that. Also - what is the type of the `Director` column?

Comment: Yes, every email address is unique to that row. All three columns are type Text.

Comment: @MichaelMeis - that's not what I asked :). If you were to count, how many times each `Work Email Address` appears in the table - would that always be 1, for each email?

Comment: @W.B. Oh sorry, yes. Each email address only appears once in the table. One Director is tied to multiple email addresses though.